# PartialView and HTTPPOST action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, http-post, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've a problem with partial view and controller HTTPPOST action : When I'm in HTTPPOST to my partialview, only partial is return, **not index page with partialview.**

I don't understand why!

The context :

I've an offer(associated with a viewmodel), composed of 4 parts : Client, SwimmingPool, Cover, Resume
I would like make to offer on a single page with partialview, one per parts.

Code in my view (Offer/Index) :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>    

    <% Html.RenderAction("P_Client"); %>          

</asp:Content>
```

Code in my controller :

public class OfferController : Controller
    {

```
    public ActionResult Index() {  

        return View();        
    }

    [HttpGet, ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult P_Client(string id)
    {
       blablabla

       return PartialView("P_Client", viewmodel);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult P_Client(OfferViewModel ViewModel)
    {                    
        return PartialView(ViewModel);        

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your Post action says

```
Return PartialView(ViewModel);
```

so that's what it does - returns a **partial** view.  Change this to

```
Return View("Index", ViewModel);
```

Comment: It doesnt work, debug loop infinitely the HttpPost ActionResult P_Client!

Comment: Ah ok.  Try replacing the line with RedirectToAction("Index")